# Weird behaving ellipsis function (va_list)

Tags: c, variadic-functions, ellipsis

The following `max` function is supposed to return 5 but it returns 4294967294 instead. I suspect the weird behavior arise from casting variables but couldn't figure it out. Can someone detect the fault?

System: Windows 7 (64 bits), mingw64

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int64_t max(int64_t n, ...) {
    va_list v;
    int64_t i, t, max = INT64_MIN;

    va_start(v, n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        t = va_arg(v, int64_t);

        if (max < t) {
            max = t;
        }
    }

    va_end(v);
    return (max);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("max(3, 1, 5, -2)   : %3I64d\n", max(3, 1, 5, -2));
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: you're trying to find the min, i think. because `max < t` doesn't make too much sense. Why would INT64_MAX be less than t?

Comment: @ssd, FYI, the conventional term for an "ellipsis function" is a *varargs function*, where "varargs" is short for "variable arguments".

Comment: Another name used for functions with ellipsis in the prototype is 'variadic function' — though the term is not used in the standard (neither is 'varargs function'). The standard uses various circumlocutions, none of them as compact — for example 'a function that accepts a variable number of arguments' (§6.9.1 ¶8).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know that  1,5 and -2 are supposed to be type `int64_t`. So it will treat them as normal ints and will only use that much space on the stack for them.

You then read them as `int64_t` which is certainly larger than `int` and so your input and your `var_args` are out of alignment.

One way to fix, cast to `int64_t` at the call site.

```
printf("max(3, 1, 5, -2)   : %"PRId64"\n", max(3, (int64_t)1, (int64_t)5, (int64_t)-2));
```

You could also obviously explicitly pass `int64_t` typed variables.

Comment: 8 **bytes**, yes thats right. As long as whatever type the arguments were and the type passed to `va_arg` match up it should work out.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll delete my prev. comment. It will be confusing: I've typed **4 bits** and **8 bits** while I really meant **4 bytes** and **8 bytes**.

Comment: You could also use `INT64_C(1), INT64_C(5), INT64_C(-2)` for the `int64_t` constants.  This doesn't make much difference here, but might matter if the constants were big enough — though the compiler will usually cope, I think.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No, don't use those. INTN_C macro gives a type int_leastN_t not intN_t.

Comment: @2501: Where the system supports the N, you'll find `int_leastN_t` is the same as `intN_t`.  You have to stretch pretty hard to devise a system where you would run into trouble — in fact, I can't think of one (but I'm running uncaffeinated so far this morning, so that may not prove anything).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The worst thing I can think of is that code compiles when it shouldn't, in absence of intN_t types.

Comment: @2501: please explain how that could occur. If it is too long for comments, please send email — see my profile.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If intN_t types aren't defined then the code obviously wouldn't compile. Although then the PRIdN specifiers will probably be missing. And OP is using intN_t types in function definitions anyway, so it won't compile for that reason.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Or you could get undefined behavior with a different approach. Have an implementation define uint_least64_t as a standard integer type of width 64, and uint64_t as an extended integer type of width 64. The types are different, and you technically get undefined behavior.